# Keras generator keeps shuffling though it is asked not to

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I use a Keras data generator initializing shuffle to false by default:

```
class data_generator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, frames, labels, batch_size, data_dir, shuffle=False):
        'Initialization'
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.labels = labels
        self.frames = frames
        self.data_dir = data_dir
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.size = len(self.frames)
        self.on_epoch_end()

  ...

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.frames))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

   ...
```

And this is how I create instances for training and validation:

```
train_generator = data_generator(x_train[:num_train_examples], y_train[:num_train_examples], batch_size, data_dir)
val_generator = data_generator(x_train[num_train_examples:], y_train[num_train_examples:], batch_size, data_dir)
```

And then train the model:

```
model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                        validation_data=val_generator,
                        callbacks=[history],
                        epochs=num_epochs)
```

But the generator keeps producing random indexes:

```
starting training
Epoch 1/1

batch start: 0, batch end: 2

batch start: 24, batch end: 26

batch start: 2, batch end: 4

batch start: 114, batch end: 116

batch start: 4, batch end: 6

batch start: 60, batch end: 62

batch start: 6, batch end: 8

batch start: 68, batch end: 70

batch start: 8, batch end: 10

batch start: 94, batch end: 96
```

What can I do to make it **not** to shuffle?

A **getitem** function from the generator class:

```
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        x_batch, y_batch = self.__data_generation(index)

        return x_batch, y_batch

    def __data_generation(self, index):
        'Generates data containing batch_size samples'
        limit = min(self.size, (index + 1)*self.batch_size)
        x_batch = []
        print('\nbatch start: ' + str(index*self.batch_size) + ', batch end: ' + str(limit))
        for frame in self.frames[index*self.batch_size:limit]:
            video_array = np.load(self.data_dir + '/' + frame + '.npy')
            x_batch.append(np.array(video_array))

        return np.array(x_batch), self.labels[index*self.batch_size:limit]
```

EDIT: Now I can see the pattern, looks like non-random batches alternate with random ones

Comment: Can you post your **__getitem__** function in the generator class?

Comment: @BashirKazimi added getitem editing the original question

Comment: I added code and explanation as an answer, please check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the problem might be in your `__len__(self)` function (if you have defined it that is). I added the `__len__(self)` function to your code and tried, it does not shuffle now. The code is here:

```
class data_generator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, frames, labels, batch_size, data_dir, shuffle=False):
        'Initialization'
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.labels = labels
        self.frames = frames
        self.data_dir = data_dir
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.size = len(self.frames)
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(self.size/self.batch_size))

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.frames))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        x_batch, y_batch = self.__data_generation(index)
        return x_batch, y_batch

    # def __data_generation(self, index):
    #     'Generates data containing batch_size samples'
    #     current_indices = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index + 1)*self.batch_size]
    #     x_batch = []
    #     y_batch = []
    #     for idx in current_indices:
    #         # video_array = np.load(self.data_dir + '/' + self.frames[idx] + '.npy')
    #         # x_batch.append(np.array(video_array))
    #         y_batch.append(self.labels[idx])

    #     return np.array(x_batch), y_batch

    def __data_generation(self, index):
        'Generates data containing batch_size samples'
        limit = min(self.size, (index + 1)*self.batch_size)
        x_batch = []
        print('\nbatch start: ' + str(index*self.batch_size) + ', batch end: ' + str(limit))
        for frame in self.frames[index*self.batch_size:limit]:
            video_array = np.load(self.data_dir + '/' + frame + '.npy')
            x_batch.append(np.array(video_array))
        return np.array(x_batch), self.labels[index*self.batch_size:limit]
```

The above code works as you expected, it does not shuffle. However, the way you have defined your *__data_generation* function, it does not work if you want it to shuffle. Therefore, I wrote my own `__data_generation` function that you can see commented out. If you use this, you can get the functionality you desire. If *shuffle* is *True*, it will shuffle. If *shuffle* is *False*, it won't shuffle. Hope it helps.